# Calculate biggest positive sequnces in numbers

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, c#-4.0

I am trying to find the biggest positive changes in the account transactions. It starts with opening balance and keep changing based on spending and deposits.

We need to find in which two dates the account contains the biggest or highest positive cash flow. I am not able to calculate and my code fails. I think my logic is wrong it gives a wrong output. Because between 8 Dec - 10 Dec account seen highest deposit or positive changes

> 12/11/2015 12:00:00 AM,   12/12/2015 12:00:00 AM,  23000

Instead

> 12/8/2015 12:00:00 AM,   12/10/2015 12:00:00 AM,  10000

[dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mGasfp)

Below is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
             var transactions = new List<Transaction>()
        {
            new Transaction() {Date = new DateTime(2015, 12, 04), Balance = -4000}, // Open with negative 4000
            new Transaction() {Date = new DateTime(2015, 12, 05), Balance = 2000}, // Settled 6000, so balance 2000
            new Transaction() {Date = new DateTime(2015, 12, 06), Balance = 0}, // Spent 2000
            new Transaction() {Date = new DateTime(2015, 12, 07), Balance = 2000}, // Deposited 2000
            new Transaction() {Date = new DateTime(2015, 12, 08), Balance = -5000}, // Spent 7000
            new Transaction() {Date = new DateTime(2015, 12, 09), Balance = 0}, // Deposited 5000
            new Transaction() {Date = new DateTime(2015, 12, 10), Balance = 5000}, // Deposited 5000
            new Transaction() {Date = new DateTime(2015, 12, 11), Balance = 1000}, // Spent 4000
            new Transaction() {Date = new DateTime(2015, 12, 12), Balance = 6000}, // Deposited 5000
        };
        
          var (start, end, biggestAmountChangePositive) = GetBiggestBalanceChangeInPositive(transactions);
         Console.WriteLine(start); //2015, 12, 08
         Console.WriteLine(end); //2015, 12, 10
         Console.WriteLine(biggestAmountChangePositive); //10000
    }
    
     public static (DateTime? start, DateTime? end, decimal biggestAmountChangePositive) GetBiggestBalanceChangeInPositive(List<Transaction> transactions)
    {
        decimal biggestAmountChangePositive = 0;
        DateTime? startDate = null;
        DateTime? endDate = null;

        for (var i = 1; i < transactions.Count; i++)
        {

            if (transactions[i].Balance > transactions[i - 1].Balance)
            {
                var change = Math.Abs(transactions[i - 1].Balance - transactions[i].Balance);
                biggestAmountChangePositive = biggestAmountChangePositive + change;
                startDate = transactions[i - 1].Date;
                endDate = transactions[i].Date;
            }
        }



        return (startDate, endDate, biggestAmountChangePositive);
    }
}

public class Transaction
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the correct answer be `8th Dec - 12th Dec`? That's a change of `11000`

Comment: @AbhinavMathur no it is like how you spend and deposit. `It got 10000 deposited between 8 and 10th Dec and 11after spending 4000 balance became 1000.` So the `biggest inflow was between 8th to 10th` Please check the comment next to them

Comment: Does the timeframe matter? eg. an increase of $300 over 30 days is $10 a day, so it should be considered smaller than an increase of $30 over 2 days which is $15 a day?

Comment: @RandRandom its not about time frame. Its about from when they started become positive cash flow until how long? In this we need to choose the highest amount

Comment: So to paraphrase, you're trying to 1) sum consecutive elements that have the same sign. 2) find the largest sum?

Answer (score 1):

I made what you asked.

I created one method and one class to remove some code.

```
    public static (DateTime? start, DateTime? end, decimal highestPositiveBalanceChange) GetBiggestBalanceChangeInPositive(List<Transaction> transactions)
    {
        DateTime? startDate = null;
        DateTime? endDate = null;
        var highestPositiveBalanceChange = decimal.MinValue;

        DateTime? tempStart = transactions[0].Date;
        DateTime? tempEnd = transactions[0].Date;
        var tempLast = transactions[0].Balance;
        decimal tempHighestPositiveBalanceChange = 0;

        for (var index = 1; index < transactions.Count; index++)
        {
            var transaction = transactions[index];

            if (transaction.Balance >= tempLast)
            {
                tempHighestPositiveBalanceChange += transaction.Balance - tempLast;
                tempLast = transaction.Balance;
                tempEnd = transaction.Date;
            }
            else
            {
                if (tempHighestPositiveBalanceChange > highestPositiveBalanceChange)
                {
                    highestPositiveBalanceChange = tempHighestPositiveBalanceChange;
                    startDate = tempStart;
                    endDate = tempEnd;

                }

                tempStart = transaction.Date;
                tempEnd = transaction.Date;
                tempLast = transaction.Balance;
                tempHighestPositiveBalanceChange = 0;
            }
        }

        if (tempHighestPositiveBalanceChange > highestPositiveBalanceChange)
        {
            highestPositiveBalanceChange = tempHighestPositiveBalanceChange;
            startDate = tempStart;
            endDate = tempEnd;

        }

        return highestPositiveBalanceChange == 0 ? (null, null, 0) : (startDate, endDate, highestPositiveBalanceChange);
    }
```

With this, you will get the 10000 that you wanted

Comment: It fails if I given only two transaction contains balance of 100 and next day 300. In this case 200 positive and first one's date should be start date and second one date should be end date

Comment: I made some changes. Try again. @Billa

Comment: Wow it looks its working and you rocking.. Is there a possibility to make it with out intermittent class like `Bigger`?

Comment: yeah I will do that

Comment: It became a little bigger than I expected but it works